# Subtract numbers from two linked list stack in java

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

Minimal reproducible example:

```
    int borrow = 0;
    int valueOne = 2;
    int valueTwo = 5;
    int sub;
    
    if(valueOne > valueTwo) {
        sub = borrow + valueOne - valueTwo;
    } else {
        sub = borrow + valueTwo - valueOne;
    }
    if (sub < 0) {
        borrow = -1;
        sub += 10;
    } else {
        borrow = 0;
    }
    System.out.format("borrow: %d; sub: %d.%n", borrow, sub);
```

Expected output:

> borrow: -1; sub: 7.

Observed output:

> borrow: 0; sub: 3.

I have two linked list stack implementations without using collections. This method is supposed to process any length numbers and subtract them. the method works when the isn't any borrowing in the process but does not work when subtraction requires borrowing. I can not figure the logic when the subtraction requires borrowing! Any help

Here is the method

```
    public static void subtractRoutine(String operndOne, String operndTwo) {
        int sub =0, borrow =0, valueOne, valueTwo;
        pushToLsLeft(padZero(operndOne, operndTwo)[ZERO]);
        pushToLsRight(padZero(operndOne, operndTwo)[ONE]);
//      System.out.println(left);
        left.reverseLinkLsStack();
        right.reverseLinkLsStack();
        while(left.sizeLinkedLs() > ZERO && right.sizeLinkedLs() > ZERO) {
            valueOne = Character.getNumericValue(left.pop());
            valueTwo = Character.getNumericValue(right.pop());
// --------------------------- please, only focus on the logic below. Everything above works fine.
            if(valueOne > valueTwo) {
                sub = borrow + valueOne - valueTwo;
            
                
            } else {
                sub = borrow + valueTwo - valueOne;
//              System.out.println(sub);
            }
            if (sub < 0) {
                borrow = -1;
                sub += 10;
            } else {
                borrow = 0;
            }
//          System.out.println(sub);
            result.push(sub);
        }
    }
```

if I input this

```
250 + -150
-250 + 150
120 + -50
```

the output would be

```
250
-150
0100

-250
150
-0100

// the problem is here
120
-50
0130
```

Comment: Hard to tell. Could you [create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can try running your code? It will help in figuring out what goes wrong.

Comment: @OleV.V. it will probably be hard to create a minimal reprod because use of multiple methods for this, sorry. I understand the importance, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based off @Ole V.V. answer here is a working solution to my problem.

First of all I had the if condition in which I was switching the position of the value one and two. This is not how subtraction work. I had to keep the value in the same position.

removed this

```
 if(valueOne > valueTwo) {
                sub = borrow + valueOne - valueTwo;
            
                
            } else {
                sub = borrow + valueTwo - valueOne;
```

Second, I reversed the stack before starting the subtraction which resulted in starting from the left to the right but the correct order should've been from the right to left.

Lastly, the subtraction order was incorrect. I need to first subtract the number then check if the number is below zero which means need to borrow so then set borrow to -1. Once all that is done, reverse the stack to the result that comes out in the correct order.

**The correct answer**

```
public void subtractRoutine(String operndOne, String operndTwo) {
        int sub =0, borrow =0, valueOne, valueTwo;
        pushToLsLeft(padZero(operndOne, operndTwo)[ZERO]);
        pushToLsRight(padZero(operndOne, operndTwo)[ONE]);
        while(left.sizeLinkedLs() > ZERO && right.sizeLinkedLs() > ZERO) {
            valueOne = Character.getNumericValue(left.pop());
            valueTwo = Character.getNumericValue(right.pop());

            sub = borrow + valueOne - valueTwo;
            if (sub < 0) {
                // when you borrow you need to add 10 
                sub = 10 + valueOne - valueTwo;
                // set borrow to -1 so the number been borrowed from cancelled out
                borrow = -1;
            } else {
                borrow = 0;
            }

            result.push(sub);
        }
        // at the end reverse the numbers in the stack 
        result.reverseLinkLsStack();
    }
```

Comment: Instead of reversing the list for arithmetic operations you might consider having the rightmost (least significant) digit at the front (head) of your list always?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand this correctly, but isn't the rightmost number is the first elem enter the stack? And are you referring to change how push work in my stack?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
            sub = borrow + valueTwo - valueOne;
```

In the situation where you should subtract 5 from 2, which requires that we borrow, you are exchanging the values and subtracting 2 from 5 instead. Which is wrong and gives the erroneous 3 in your result, 130. And also causes us not to borrow as we should.

You don’t need this `if`-`else` statement at all:

```
        if(valueOne > valueTwo) {
```

The subtraction should be the same no matter which digit is greater. Only the borrow part will be different depending on whether you get a negative difference at first.